# Who owns Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Pretty straightforward question, really: Who has an ownership stake in Stack Overflow?

Comment: There's an [About](https://stackoverflow.com/company) link at the bottom of every page on every site in the Stack Exchange network...

Comment: @HereticMonkey …which just says that it is owned by the Stack Overflow corporation, and gives a short history. That’s why I asked.

Comment: There is no evidence, in the question, that you had read even that much. I was pointing you to the place where you could begin your own research to find the answer yourself...

Comment: "you could begin your own research to find the answer yourself..." That's something, you could say to almost every question asked there. This is the point of this page

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On June 2nd, 2021, Stack Overflow announced it is being acquired by Prosus for 1.8 billion USD.

References:

- [Prosus’s Acquisition of Stack Overflow: Our Exciting Next Chapter](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/)
- [Prosus to acquire Stack Overflow for US$1.8 billion](https://www.prosus.com/news/prosus-to-acquire-stack-overflow-for-us18-billion/)
- [Kinda a big announcement - Joel Spolsky (CEO of Stack Overflow from 2010-2019)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2021/06/02/kinda-a-big-announcement/)

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you mean the company Stack Overflow then all we know it is privately held, since it was founded in 2008 by Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood.

Since then multiple venture capitalists put money up for the company so I assume they do that in return for a stake but for obvious reasons which stake is kept secret and there is no obligation to make that public.

See the timeline on the [Company page](https://stackoverflow.com/company)

Comment: Part of the 'value' paid out to each of the companies who donated money is a seat on the board of directors, whose membership one can see at the bottom of the page here: https://stackoverflow.com/company/management

Comment: @TylerH beyond that, the fact that each of the 5 investors has a single seat on the board implies that they probably all own similar sized shares of the company.  if one of them had a share that was several times larger than the average they'd also probably have multiple seats on the board.

Comment: @TylerH I guess you mean "donate". VCs are not charities.

Comment: @rene Yes, of course. Slip of the <strikethrough>tongue</strikethrough> fingers, you know...